# Problemas al ordenar array en javascript y un chat que estoy creando

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, socket, socket.io

ando creando un chat con sockets en nodejs que dicen que es muy bueno. Entonces creo un array:

```
let nicknames = [];
```

que guardará los nombres de usuarios para que luego el frontend se encargue de mostrarlos en una lista. Eso me funciona perfecto.

Entonces, tengo un evento llamado connection que detecta cuando se conecta un usuario al chat y lo agrega a la lista:

```
//Cuando un usuario se conecta y el socket escucha
  io.on("connection", socket => {
    socket.on('new user', (data, cb) => {
        console.log("Se conecto "+data);
        if (nicknames.indexOf(data) != -1) {
            cb(false);
        } else {
            cb(true);
            socket.nickname = data;
            nicknames.push(socket.nickname);
        nicknames = nicknames.sort();
        updateNicknames();
        io.sockets.emit("nad", socket.nickname);
      }
    });
```

Hasta ahí todo vuelve a estar bien, inclusive, el método .sort() me ordena los usuarios por orden alfabético como debe de ser. Y la función updateNicknames(); es la que se encarga de mandar los usuarios ordenados al frontend:

```
function updateNicknames() {
        io.sockets.emit('usernames', nicknames);
    }
```

para que este los muestre en la lista de la siguiente forma:

```
socket.on('usernames', data =>{
    let html = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      html += `<p><i class="fas fa-user"></i> ${data[i]} </p>`;
    }
    $users.html(html);
  })
```

El problema es cuando quiero que se desconecte un usuario, siempre se desconecta el ultimo que salio sin importar cual fuese el usuario que realmente se desconecta:

```
socket.on('disconnect', data => {
      if(!socket.nickname) return;
      io.sockets.emit("nod", socket.nickname);

      nicknames.splice(nicknames.indexOf(socket.nickanme), 1);
      updateNicknames();

    });
```

Esta linea es la que desconecta al usuario y entonces el updateNicknames() se encarga nuevamente de enviar la lista ordenada al frontend.

```
nicknames.splice(nicknames.indexOf(socket.nickanme), 1);
```

no se por qué no se desconecta el usuario que quiero.

Comment: por que estas eliminando el ultimo elemento del array con la funcion splice

Comment: y a cual debo eliminar? se me ocurre recorrer el array, pero como hago para saber cual es el que tengo que eliminar?

Comment: el usuario debe mandar un evento mandando su id y luego recorres el id verificando en el array, luego eliminas el id del user en el array, enviando eventos por medio de sockets

Comment: Podrías probar, cuando un usuario se desconecte, a registrar el nickname que te viene. Y también qué índice te devuelve esta expresión `nicknames.indexOf(socket.nickanme)`

Comment: Por cierto, veo que tienes una errata en `nicknames.indexOf(socket.nickanme)` (nickANme)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que esto es lo que necesitas, identificar que socket es al momento de eliminar. Cuando el usuario ingresa se asigna el los datos del usuario con el key socket.id (nicknames[socket.id] = data)

Cuando el usuario por algun motivo se desconecta el elimina el objecto del array por el socket asignado (delete nicknames[socket.id];)

```js
socket.on('new user', (data, cb) => {
  nicknames[socket.id] = data
}

socket.on('disconnect', function () {
  delete nicknames[socket.id];
}
```

Comment: Perfecto, justo lo que necesitaba.